# Calculate Var(X+X) based on definiton of variance

Tags: statistics

So I understand $Var(X)=\sum_{\omega\in\Omega} (X(\omega)-E(X))^2P(\omega)$

Which means $Var(X + X)=\sum_{omega\in\Omega} (X(\omega) + X(\omega) - E(X+X))^2P(\omega)$

Suppose X describes throwing a dice with numbers 1 to 6, this means $Var(X + X)=\sum_{\omega\in\Omega} (X(\omega) + X(\omega) - 7)^2P(\omega)$

What's the difference of this from 2X?

Comment: There is an ambiguity here, as to whether $X+X$ should instead be read as $X+Y$ where $Y$ is an independent variable, identically distributed to $X$.  With your dice example, this ambiguity is the same as distinguishing between two independent throws of a fair die and doubling a single throw.

Comment: $X+X=2X$, but you may have intended this to be two independent dice

Comment: It is indeed intended as two independent dice. I found an answer by myself already btw. How can I mark this question as answered?

Comment: You can post your own solution.

Comment: Thanks. Already did it

Answer (score 0):

By 2 independent dice throws: $\omega\in\Omega_1=\{(1,1),(1,2),...,(6,6)\}$

so $Var(X+X)=\sum_{\omega\in\Omega_1} ((X+X)(\omega)-7)^2P(\omega)=5.83333$

By 1 dice throw and multiply it with 2: $\omega\in\Omega_2=\{2,4,6,...,12\}$

so $Var(2X)=\sum_{\omega\in\Omega_2} ((2X)(\omega)-7)^2P(\omega)=11.666$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).